# VB.NET Method parameters syntax error for DateTime data Type

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I keep on getting the error of "Value of type 'Date' cannot be converted to 'Decimal?'" for ClosingDate

Please help me.

```
   Public Function Update(ByVal pAccountID As Short, ByVal pAccountTypeID As Short,ByVal pCustomerName As String, ByVal pOpeningDate As DateTime, ByVal pClosingDate As DateTime, ByVal pBalance As Double) As Boolean

    catchError = String.Empty
    Try
        accountTableAdapter.Update(AccountID, AccountTypeID, CustomerName, OpeningDate,    ClosingDate, Balance)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        catchError = ex.Message
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: We need to know what the signature of `accountTableAdapter.Update` is.

Comment: Public Overridable Overloads Function Update(ByVal dataTable As JagBankDataSet.CustAccountsDataTable) As Integer
             Return Me.Adapter.Update(dataTable)

Answer (score 0):

probably you have set the `accountTableAdapter`s closingDate's column data type as `Decimal`. You need to change it to `DateTime`